# How to Compute Digits of factorial in best efficient

Tags: c++, factorial, digits

I know the way to compute digits of factorial in the following manner.

let digits of n! to be found.

```
temp = 0.0;
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){ 
temp += log(i);
}
result = (int)temp;
result++;
```

i'm here looking for more efficient way to count digits of factorial.

N.B: please ans in coding with  C++

Comment: I'm not sure the code you're giving even works. What's with `
result++; = (int)temp;` ??

Comment: it was my mistake. now corrected. thanks

Answer (score -1):

the pythonic solution for this problem:

```
len(list(str(num)))
```

in c for computing digits of every number you can use this code:

```
int c=2;
while((num/10)>10) {
    num=(int)a/10;
    c++;
    }
```

Comment: you don't know python or don't have python? if you don't have python you can use online interpreter such as: [link](http://repl.it/languages/Python)

Comment: I don't see how this helps answer the question

Comment: i don't know python. i only know C and C++. plz help me with C++ #Sara_Santana